# how to properly override serializer save on a POST request in DRF?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model that has a DateTime field and a serializer for that model.  I have an API endpoint that is POST only to create the model object, but the problem is the requests to this endpoint will send a completely different date/time format, and so this will need to be reformatted on Django's end before saving.

Normally (without DRF), I would just override the models save method, but now with the introduction of DRF, I'm confused if I should be override the save method for the model or the serializer?  I'm thinking if I override the save method for the model so that it reformats the date/time value before saving.  Then the serializer.is_valid() itself will throw an error when receiving the wrong date time format since the serializer maps directly to the model fields and has no knowledge of the models save method?

What is the best way to go about doing this?

models.py

```
class Job(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('name', 'age', 'start_time')
```

serializers.py

```
class JobSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    age = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    start_time = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ('name', 'age', 'start_time')
```

Comment: Your reasoning is hard to follow. The serializer should responsible for creating data in the format the model expects it. It's not the save you should be changing, but the field validation - although I don't understand why you have used a CharField rather than a DateTimeField with the relevant `input_formats`.

Answer (score 2):

As Daniel mentioned, a Serializer should be responsible for converting your content data types (API data) to native datatypes which are fed to your model and any modification or validation of that data should also be handled by the serializer itself.

For the validation with DRF serializers, there are Field-level validation and Object-level validation which can be used for validating your start_time field.

Field level validation ->

```
def validate_start_time(self, value):
    #validation
    return value
```

Object-level validation

```
def validate(self, data):
    #obj validation if required e.g want to combine some data into one or mix match
    return data
```

and can use the datetime field in the serializer instead,

```
 start_time = serializers.DateTimeField()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include formatting for input value in field level validation. In your serializer include the following method:

```
def validate_start_time(self, value):
    # format value here
    return value
```

More info on field level validation: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation